# Less than 10 rep for an upvote without hitting the reputation cap?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Apologies in advance if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find it.

The reputation summary on SO tells me I received 180 reputation today (if I click the envelope icon, then "summary", then "today").  As I understand it this is 20 less than the cap of 200.  [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008891/any-ideas-on-optimizing-this-script-python/2008920#2008920) that I posted earlier (within the last two hours), before I reached 180, has 1 upvote and 0 downvotes and earned 7 reputation.  My [most recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009228/strings-are-objects-in-java-but-we-dont-use-new-to-declare-a-string-why/2009272#2009272) has 7 upvotes and 0 downvotes and has earned 5 reputation.  No CW stuff is involved, as far as I can tell.

Can anyone explain to me what's happening here?

**Edit**, in response to Marc, but also as an afterthought: no, I haven't done a lot of downvoting nor been downvoted.  Specifically, I haven't reached the cap and then gone down to 180 or anything like that, nor do I have enough downvoting to make the difference.  Nor did I reach the cap at all, to my knowledge.

**Edit 2**:  Marc's point about unaccepted answers seems valid, except for that it happened that two questions got weird (<10) amounts of reputation.  Still possible?

**Edit 3**: it happened again today.  I was at 182 reputation for the day, including -3 in downvotes, and I just received 7 points for an upvote, capping me at 189.  So frustrating.  I'm almost certain I didn't reach 200 at any point today.

**Edit 3.5**: Right after I typed that, I had two answers accepted, putting me at 219.  I thought about the case where one of those got in while I was still at 182, but that would put me up to 197 and then I would have received 3 for the last upvote, not 7.

Comment: You should associate your account on meta with the one on SO. Right now, if I click on your account name here, I can't see any SO associated account. It will also give you 100 rep points here.

Comment: Much better! You should have also received a little extra on SO, I believe.

Comment: Thought of another possibility

Comment: 100 rep points? I didn't get no stinkin' rep points! Now I feel left out...

Comment: @Clueless: I believe you need 200 rep points on _one_ of the sites. You've got that as I can see. Disassociating the re-associating accounts and should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting... this pattern is repeated on [Jon's rep tracker](http://csharpindepth.com/StackOverflow/ReputationTracker.aspx?so=217332). Have you perhaps done lots of downvoting today? The other possibility is that you've had some answers *unaccepted* - i.e. you hit the cap briefly, and then have had points subtracted due to losing a green tick on an old answer.

Oh, there is another possibility - it sometimes happens that a well-meaning overly grateful user upvotes your account heavily, triggering suspicious voting patterns. This then cancels the suspicious votes; it is possible that 2 of these votes were part of your days rep.

i.e. say you had +180, and then somebody upvoted you like a crazy mad thing; you'd max at +200, the rest would be discarded, and then (at some point) their 30 (or whatever) votes are cancelled taking you back to +180. Don't ask me the exact details of the suspicious voting algorithm, as I genuinely don't know.

Comment: Sorry, I reread - I guess its not all that unthinkable that two answers were unaccepted after hitting the cap.  But, suppose that did happen - would it be possible for me to hit the cap twice (getting amounts of 7 and 5)?  It seems that if this was going to happen, then after the cap was hit once, nothing could give me reputation.

Comment: Would the algorithm kick in this fast?

Comment: I honestly don't know. Unfortunate timing vs a scheduled task, perhaps?

Comment: Is it the case then that once you hit the cap, you can't get any more rep via upvotes that day no matter how much you lose via un-upvotes, un-accepts, etc?