# 9 reputation points for a up vote

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
>   [Less than 10 rep for an upvote without hitting the reputation cap?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34614/less-than-10-rep-for-an-upvote-without-hitting-the-reputation-cap)

I just notice that I had receive +9 reputation points for a upvote. At the time I had 185 points accumulated (today). I just go to see the upvote details and I had +2/0 votes, one counted as +10 and the other +9.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Congratulations, you've hit the repcap.

Comment: But the repcap do not only happen when you pass 200?

Comment: @BoPersson: Not sure that's the best dupe target..

Comment: I can delete the question, if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You hit the reputation cap. Normally, that'd mean [your rep page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1366871/dreamcrash?tab=reputation) would show 200 points for the day, but...
[image: unaccept for -15 points]

Since reputation earned - or lost - from accepted answers is exempt from the cap, you actually hit 200 points at 185 (+another 100 for the association bonus) today.

Comment: Yep it was that. Although, do not makes a lot of sense. I could not win more points yesterday because I reach the repcap (with the +15 from that answer) and today I can't get more because of that answer again xD

Comment: @dreamcrash: actually, that +15 yesterday didn't count toward your cap. Or to look at it another way, you would've had to hit 215 to cap yesterday, just as you only needed 185 today (in practice, you got 7 accepts yesterday, putting your rep cap at over 300).

Comment: Oh, right! Accepted answers do not count on this equation. Thanks