# Only received 2 rep for an upvote

Tags: support, reputation, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

Earlier today I was at 168 reputation for the day, when I received an upvote on an answer of mine.  Instead of receiving 10 reputation like I would have expected I only gained 2.  I don't mind much having 7 rep less, I would have liked to get a point towards epic, but I have plenty of time left to hit the cap.  However I couldn't find an explanation as to why this happened, so I thought I would bring it here in case anyone has experienced this before.

[image: reputation]

Why might I only receive 2 rep when I'm not at the rep cap?

[This question is similar but I never hit the rep cap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34614/less-than-10-rep-for-an-upvote-without-hitting-the-reputation-cap)

[Also similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125152/i-got-no-rep-for-an-upvote-while-not-hitting-the-rep-cap)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained [in the faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/152859), the daily reputation cap is **not for total reputation**, but rather reputation from upvotes and suggested edits.

Sum the upvotes you got today and you do have 200:

> [image]

The -30 due to removed user does not affect the daily reputation cap. You can still reach 200 (and more) by getting your answers accepted, etc.

Comment: Ah I see, I was counting the user removed as unupvotes, I suppose they are not.

Comment: Yup, different events.

Comment: @EpsilonNeighborhoodWatch Actually, unupvotes also don't make the cap "larger", unless it is an unupvote of an upvote cast the same day.